# Sketch works on Arduino nano but not Pro Mini

Tags: arduino-pro-mini

I have a simple test sketch to run for my led aquarium:

```
#include <IRremote.h>
#include <IRremoteInt.h>

IRsend irsend;
void setup() {

}

void loop() {

irsend.sendNEC(0xF7C03F, 32);
delay (2000);
}
```

I am using a 850nm Infrared LED and a 330Ohm resistor.
The connection:
Digital 3 to Resistor -> GND
[image]

On the Arduino nano it runs perfectly: the LED of my aquarium turns on and off like the sketch tells it to.
But on the Pro Mini nothing happens.

To be honest, it is my first time using the pro mini. 
Maybe I forgot something???
I am using a FTDI232 (set to 5V) to flash it.

Hope someone can help me. 
Kind regard 
Daniel :)

Comment: Can you confirm, that the sketch really runs? You can use the Blink Sketch with a normal LED, so that you can see, if the sketch really runs, that you programmed onto the pro mini

Comment: Can you verify that the led lights up? I used the front-facing camera of my iPhone to see if my IR-led was blinking. Secondly; which pro-mini variant are you using? The 3.3V or the 5V one? Make sure you selected the correct one in the "boards" menu.

Comment: Yes, the blink sketch seems to run. The LED next to pin 9 turns on/off for 2 secs.

Comment: I think it is the 5V variant. (I measured VCC and GND and it gave me 5V).

Comment: how is that resistor connected on breadboard? in the same column?

Comment: Yes, the resistor is in the same colum. On the breadboard it is in "h" and "i" the led is in the same column in "j".

Comment: I checked with my phone, the led lights up. It is just a millisecond or so, but it lights up.

Comment: I recorded the signal, that was sent from the arduinos: pro mini: FA34C27F        nano: different signal every time it sends, nevertheless the led of my aquarium reacts to the nano signal.

Comment: the resistor in the same column does nothing. it is like it wouldn't be there